# How to create a table from entity in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, unit-testing, doctrine-orm

I see similar questions at SO, but they are outdated and no longer actual. So, what I want is to create tables in database using models definition. So, I have a model which looks like so:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Integration\Models;

/**
* @Entity
* @Table(name="test_model")
*/
class TestModel
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    protected $a;


    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getA()
    {
        return $this->a;
    }

    public function setA($a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}
```

In my unit-test I have a working code, looking like:

```
    <?php

namespace Tests\Integration;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Tests\Integration\Models\TestModel;
use Tests\Integration\Models\TestModelRepository;


final class IntegrationOrmTest extends TestCase
{
    protected static $em;

    protected static $er;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        $params = [
            'driver' => getenv("TEST_DB_DRIVER"),
            'host' => getenv("TEST_DB_HOST"),
            'dbname' => getenv("TEST_DB_NAME"),
            'user' => getenv("TEST_DB_USER"),
            'password' => getenv("TEST_DB_PASSWORD"),
            'port' => getenv("TEST_DB_PORT"),
        ];

        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(["./Models"], true);
        self::$em = EntityManager::create($params, $config);
        self::$er = new TestModelRepository(self::$em);           
    }

    public function testEquals()
    {
        //works perfectly fine
        $data = new TestModel();
        $data->setA(123);
        self::$er->save($data);
        self::$em->flush();

        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

This code works, just because in my database there is already a table `test_model`. But I want to create it dynamically in my test suit and destroy it after all tests. How can I do it programmatically?

Comment: Using test env with local sqlite db ?

Comment: @Andrea Manzi. I'm using it with postgresql database

Comment: do you want create and drop only test_model? How many entities are there in your project?

Comment: So what relevant code did you actually try?  Should be just a question of creating a SchemaTool instance and then doing a drop/create schema.

Comment: @Cerad. I do not know what code to try. I tried Doctrine DBAL and it works, but now I need to do the same thing with ORM entities.

Comment: @Andrea Manz. For a start, I need to create and drop only test_model. If I know how to do it, I will scale this solution to other models as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Doctrine docs describe [schema generation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/tools.html#database-schema-generation) in some detail.

Here is a simple example:

```
final class IntegrationOrmTest extends TestCase
{
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        $params = [
            'driver' => "pdo_mysql",
            'host' => "localhost",
            'dbname' => "s43x",
            'user' => "impd",
            'password' => "JalenHurts",
            //'port' => getenv("TEST_DB_PORT"),
        ];

        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(["./Models"], true);
        self::$em = $em = EntityManager::create($params, $config);

        $tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($em);
        $classes = array(
            $em->getClassMetadata(TestModel::class),
        );
        $tool->dropSchema($classes);  // Empty out any current schema
        $tool->createSchema($classes);
```

Comment: I updated my answer to show $config.  Basically the same as yours though I'm not using getenv.